# How to @include() my secret file without error text (when there's no file) but with error text if any error is in this file?

Tags: php, error-handling, include

```
$admpage=md5($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]).'.php';
if(!@include($admpage)){echo "error opening Adminpage";}
```

So, in case there's no such file there should be error `error opening Adminpage`.

But if in included file IS error in code, it shows nothing.

In other words, I need to turn off errors reporting while including, but turn them on while executing included file.

PS
I tried `eval()` but that is much worse then `@include()`

PPS
 I need to include any files, but if error (while encluding or executing), then show error but never show filename

Comment: Use `is_readable` to check whether the file exists and is readable.

Comment: Is this an attempt for authentication? I see no point in obscuring a included file's name...

Comment: @Linus Kleen if this is possible then why not? Index files can be easily stolen, but others not so.

Comment: What do you mean by "stolen"? Are you referring to an "index.php" file?

Comment: @Linus Kleen I meam 'somehow downloaded' from server. I've encountered one time with my own code that was published in another site, what I never did. And it was `index.php` but no other files, that were with it in the same folder. So I try to hide admin part.

Comment: There's really no point to this at all. On a live web site (not in development) you will have `display_errors` off, and such errors will go to the system logs, not the browser.

Comment: @E L I imagine your **index.php** was once downloaded and stolen because you’re writing insecure code like above and trying to do things in way that cause more security issues than fix.

Comment: @EL I would guess "somehow downloaded" refers to either a site hack due to insecure code or someone gained access to your site's FTP account? In either way, I'd suggest reading up on security measures. Simply hiding a page won't cut it. Once an intruder has access to your site's file system structure, any file can be read.

Comment: @Linus Kleen I think that file was "stolen" when server's php engine was off

Comment: In that case I'd suggest switching providers. There's no reason a PHP engine suddenly just "switches off"; it's a module loaded into the server. Let's continue that in chat if you like.

Comment: @Linus Kleen I just need that `admin-****.php` name was obscured in index.php file

Comment: To avoid offering the PHP source as a download the right thing is to place the source outside of the document root, and only have one PHP file left that bootstraps and includes the needed file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, your goal is to suppress error messages from including a non-existent file.

This is how you could do this:

```
$old = ini_set('display_errors', 0);  // Do not show errors to client
$fileExists = file_exists($someFile) && is_readable($someFile);
ini_set('display_errors', $old); // Restore old value
if (!$fileExists)
   die('Error opening admin page');
include($someFile);
```

**Why the many steps?**

`file_exists` and also `is_readable` will print error messages on certain conditions: there could be a `safe_mode` or `open_basedir` restriction issue (not everyone uses PHP 5.3 already). The server might also run with `suPHP` which will make a file unreadable, too.

**Why is it wrong?**

*Your concept*: Relying on an obscured file's name for pseudo-authentication is called "security by obscurity". For example, anyone with access to your browser history would know the URL. This isn't very safe...

*My answer*: Simply turning off `display_errors` is as safe as setting `error_reporing` to zero: simply not. E.g.: once a custom error handler is being installed, both these settings are "ignored". It is the custom error handler's responsibility to check these values accordingly.

You might consider using different `php.ini` settings for both your production and development environment. The first should ideally show no error messages whatsoever, whereas the the latter should spill all of them.

---

Read up on:

- [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)
- [HTTP authentication with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)
- [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: `ccess to your browser history would know the URL` - how is it possuble, if the `obscured file` is included in index.php (which is also obscured in url)?

Comment: You're using a *fixed* constant (`DOCUMENT_ROOT`) as "obscuration" source. So if I access "http://example.com/foo.php" or "http://example.com/bar.php", the result is the same. Given both have the same document root.

Comment: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is more than "example.com/bar.php` it's something like `/php5/localfiles/home/username_xxx/` which is not accessible from browser

Comment: And how do you access this page? With a browser, maybe? And why use `md5` to obscure it, if it isn't accessible from the outside?

Comment: nobody can tell what is `DOCUMENT_ROOT` by reading just `index.php` file. And admin page is accessed with inclusion, not via browser's url\

Comment: Yeah. Ok. I'll give you that. Still: how about protecting your administration files via server directives (I assume you're using Apache)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38278/discussion-between-linus-kleen-and-e-l)

Answer (score 0):

What's about [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)?

```
if(!file_exists($admpage)){echo "error opening Adminpage";}
```

---

If you really want to just turn off error reporting while including like this: `@include("script.php");`
then wrap the code in the file in a function, e.g. `myFunc()` and then call that after the include.

Comment: that's not what I need. I need to include any files, but if error (while encluding or executing), then show error but never show filename

Comment: @EL please update your question, it's not clear that you want that.

Answer (score 0):

Only include when the file does exist using:

```
if (file_exists($admpage) && is_readable($admpage)) {
  include($admpage);
}
```

Comment: You're propagating bad coding.

Comment: @Jordi Kroon that's not what I need. I need to include any files, but if error (while encluding or executing), then show error but never show filename.

Comment: @LinusKleen And you? Don't provide anything except downvotes ... so why don't you comment or post your super solution then?

Comment: @djot I shall reveal my "super solution" once enough of my questions (which can be posted as comments) have been answered. Your answer is prone to error messages also. It doesn't solve to OP's problem, as it's unclear, what the goal is.

Comment: @LinusKleen This is a general problem of SO, and you voting down everything does not help much in this. And propagating "your godlike" answers is really ...